# Julia | Push or Append in 2 Dimensional Array

Tags: julia

I am trying to push or append elements from a 2 dimensional array to a 3 dimensional array. The array 2 (2nd dimension) is associated with an index that goes like this [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5...] and I would like the last element of the same index to be pushed / appended to array 1, that is the 1st, the 3rd, the 6th, the 10th elements etc.. Here is the MWE:

```
arr1 = Array{Float64,3}(length, per, ro)
arr2 = Array{Float64,2}(length, per * ro * (ro + 1) ÷ 2)

length = 100
per = 20
ro = 10

for l in 1:length
    for p in 1:per
        for r in 1:ro

         x = arr2[l, p * ro * (ro + 1) ÷ 2] 
         push!(arr1, x)

        end
    end
end
```

Thank you for your time.

Λ

Comment: Deques only work with arrays of dimension 1 (ie vectors). This is not a constraint of the language but rather a constraint of how higher dimensional arrays are organised in your machines memory (ie it is a constraint in all languages). You either have to completely rebuild the array you want to `push!` to (which gets very expensive), or else change your datastructure, eg maybe `Vector{Vector{Vector{T}}}`

Comment: Thank you but I do not understand, since I am very new in Julia or in Programming in general. Can you be more clear?

Comment: Let `x = [1 2 ; 3 4]`. To add a new row to `x` you would need to re-allocate it as follows: `x = vcat(x, [5, 6]')`. This command re-allocates the entire matrix and so is expensive for large matrices, but it is the only way to add a new row to a matrix since, in your machines memory, the `5` needs to be inserted betweeen the `3` and the `2`, while the `6` can be tacked on to the end after the `4`. (julia uses column-major ordering, but the principle is the same for languages that use row-major ordering).

Comment: you should preallocate your 3d array (this is what you are doing anyways) and then instead of `push!` simply do `arr1[l, p, r] = x` in your loop.